# How Terraform rotate Azure AD app secrets

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to do the azure service principle password rotation using Terraform, with the latest versions of azuread they have provided this rotation feature,

```
resource "time_rotating" "test" {
  rotation_years = 5
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "service_principal_password" {
  service_principal_id = var.sp_internal_id
    rotate_when_changed = {
    rotation = time_rotating.test.id
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I just want to when I add the attribute rotate_when_changed it will create a new password resource according to the timestamp I set right ? and I want to know that this is a feature that Terraform only provides or this is a feature from Azure AD ? since Azure AD does not provide the key rotation feature, I'm wondering how Terraform is achieving this rotation ?

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT I checked the docs looks like its still there with the latest version https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_password and I just tested this, it will recreate the password resource with this configuration

Comment: Sorry, it was a issue in my script, as it was using v2.0.1 azuread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just want to when I add the attribute rotate_when_changed it will
> create a new password resource according to the timestamp I set right
> ? and I want to know that this is a feature that Terraform only
> provides or this is a feature from Azure AD ? since Azure AD does not
> provide the key rotation feature, I'm wondering how Terraform is
> achieving this rotation ?

You are correct its a **terraform feature only** and ***not a AzureAD feature***. When we create a password from terraform it no longer uses value and if you are not providing any `end_date_relative` then it sets the expiry to a default value of 2 years. But due to security reasons if we wanted to change the value of the password as per time rotation then we can just set the `rotate_when_changed` and modify it.

This was suggested and enhanced in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/480).

**Example:**

**I used the below code to rotate the value after an hour:**

```
resource "time_rotating" "test" {
  rotation_hours = 1
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "example" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.example.object_id
  rotate_when_changed = {
    rotation = time_rotating.test.id
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

**Initial Output:**

[image]

After 1 Hour if I do a terraform Plan , then it shows that the password will be replaced as below , but before 1 hour it will just show no changes detected:

[image]

**Note:** This is useful as you won't have to destroy the password block again and recreate it . Only when your time rotation gets completed , if you perform apply then terraform will just replace the password block and again set the time rotation as per your requirement.

Comment: Thnaks, and what about password end date ? it didn't got changed right ?

Comment: @uvindusri, it remains 2 years but from the present time , when the password gets recreated.

Comment: you can also set that in application password block with `end_date_relative=xxxh` which will be in terms of hours .